# Excel Styles and Chart from Pandas Dataframe in Single Excel

Tags: python, pandas, charts, formatting, styleframe

I am having a Pandas dataframe, which I need to write it to an excel and then do color formating and plot a chart on the same sheet.

I have used StyleFrame to do the Coloring & Borders to my Dataframe, but this StyleFrame not works with Pandas XlsxWriter Object. And in turn, Plotting of chart from this styled dataframe is not working.

Can any one please share the solution for this!?

```
import pandas as pd
import xlfunc
import genfunc
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler, utils

def applystyle(df):
    sf=StyleFrame(df)

    sf.apply_column_style(cols_to_style=df.columns,
                          styler_obj=Styler(bg_color=utils.colors.white, bold=True, font=utils.fonts.calibri,
                                            font_size=8), style_header=True)
    sf.apply_headers_style(
        styler_obj=Styler(bg_color=utils.colors.blue, bold=True, font_size=8, font_color=utils.colors.white,
                          number_format=utils.number_formats.general, protection=False))

    sf.set_column_width(columns=sf.columns, width=15)
    sf.set_row_height(rows=sf.row_indexes, height=12)
    return sf


def createchart(regionname,workbook,outxl,sheetname,cellid,charttitle,startrow,startcol,endrow,endcol):

    worksheet = outxl.sheets[sheetname]
    kpichart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
    bsckpi = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

    for col_num in range(startcol+1, endcol-1):
        kpichart.set_title(
            {'name': charttitle, 'name_font': {'name': 'Cambria', 'size': 18, 'color': '#000000'}})
        kpichart.add_series({
            'name': [sheetname, startrow, col_num],
            'categories': [sheetname, startrow+1, 1, endrow, 1],
            'values': [sheetname, startrow+1, col_num, endrow, col_num],
        })
    nodekpi.add_series({
        'name': [sheetname, startrow, endcol-1],
        'categories': [sheetname,startrow+1,1,endrow,1],
        'values': [sheetname,startrow+1,endcol-1,endrow,endcol-1],
        'y2_axis': True,
    })
    kpichart.combine(nodekpi)
    kpichart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Date'})
    kpichart.set_x_axis({'num_font': {'name': 'Cambria', 'size': 10, 'color': '#000000'}})
    kpichart.set_y_axis({'name': charttitle, 'minor_gridlines': {'visible': True, 'color': '#FFFFFF'}})
    kpichart.set_y_axis({'num_font': {'name': 'Cambria', 'size': 10, 'color': '#000000'}})

    worksheet.insert_chart(cellid, kpichart, {'x_scale': 1.75, 'y_scale': 1.25})


def df_to_xl(regionname,hostlist,timerdf,hostData):

    outxl = pd.ExcelWriter("timer_audit_data.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    stylexl = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter("timer_audit_data_styled.xlsx")
    outxl.sheets.clear()
    workbook = outxl.book
    stylebook = stylexl.book

    style_timerdf = applystyle(timerdf)
    style_timerdf.to_excel(stylexl, sheet_name='Parameters', index=False)


    timerdfnew = timerdf

    # Pivot
    timer_summary = timerdfnew.pivot_table(values='NODE', index='HOST', columns='timer', aggfunc="count")
    timer_summary = applystyle(timer_summary)
    timer_summary.to_excel(stylexl, sheet_name='Parameters', startrow=0, startcol=15)

    for hostname in hostlist:
        hostname = genfunc.toString(hostname)
        hostData.to_excel(outxl,sheet_name=hostname,startrow=1,startcol=1,index=False)        
        createchart(regionname,workbook,outxl,hostname,'G2',"Timer Performance"+hostname,1,1,tr+1,tc+1)
        #In this Section I am pasting the dataframe to excel workbook & I am preparing a chart in the same sheet
        #But here i would like to apply some colors and borders to hostData pasted in excel and then I want to prepare chart in the same sheet

    outxl.save()
    stylexl.save()
```

Comment: "StyleFrame not works with Pandas XlsxWriter Object" It definitely should and even has its own `ExcelWriter` method to create it. Please provide the code you have used.

Comment: @DeepSpace I have pasted my code in the Question now, here i am passing some dataframe from main code and want that dataframe to be given in excel with charts and styled data tables

Answer (score 3):

It would be much better if you draw your chart using openpyxl package since StyleFrame uses openpyxl engine and xlsxwriter package does not work with existing files as far as I know.

This example works for me with openpyxl version 2.2.5 and StyleFrame version 1.2

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.charts import BarChart, Reference, Series
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler, utils


def apply_style(sf):
    sf.apply_headers_style(styler_obj=Styler(bg_color=utils.colors.black, font_color=utils.colors.white, bold=True))
    sf.apply_column_style(cols_to_style=sf.columns, styler_obj=Styler(font_color=utils.colors.blue))

    return sf


def draw_chart_openpyxl(worksheet):
    # pos: (row, column)
    chart = BarChart()
    labels = Reference(worksheet, pos1=(2, 1), pos2=(4, 1))

    valuesA = Reference(worksheet, pos1=(2, 2), pos2=(4, 2))
    seriesA = Series(valuesA, title='A', labels=labels)
    chart.append(seriesA)

    valuesB = Reference(worksheet, pos1=(2, 3), pos2=(4, 3))
    seriesB = Series(valuesB, title='B', labels=labels)
    chart.append(seriesB)

    chart.drawing.top = 100
    chart.drawing.left = 200
    chart.drawing.width = 300
    chart.drawing.height = 200
    worksheet.add_chart(chart)
    return worksheet


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ew = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [1, 2, 3],
        'B': [4, 5, 6]
    }, columns=['A', 'B'], index=['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3'])

    sf = StyleFrame(df)
    sf = apply_style(sf)
    sf.to_excel(excel_writer=ew, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    draw_chart_openpyxl(ew.book.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1'))
    ew.save()
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/theorchard/openpyxl/blob/master/openpyxl/sample/charts.py) many usage examples.

Comment: Can you pls explain this part pos1=(2, 1), pos2=(2, 3)? How do I modify the Categories and Data Range. Also please let me know how to add a secondary axis chart in this

Comment: I edited the answer so it contains now what you asked for. I also added a reference to usage examples.

Comment: Thanks, Now I can understand how to modify the category and data range. In this example, I can combine two charts into a single chart. Could you please tell me how to add a Secondary axis chart as well? I mean one data range in Primary axis and the other in Secondary axis.